# Debugging - How to profile react native memory usage

Tags: ios, debugging, memory, react-native, profiling

General question. I'm developing an app using React Native, and certain actions bring my app up to around 500MB of RAM, where it usually gets killed.

I've searched the web for good material on RN memory profiling but have found nothing. I've tried using Instruments, but it's output doesn't give me much insight as to what are my memory guzzling processes.

TL;DR: Do you have a good way of profiling memory usage in React Native?

P.S. currently focusing on iOS.

Thanks in advance!
Uri

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xcode and Android studio for this case.
On Xcode, you can check below screenshot.
[image]

Also for the Android Studio, you can open profiler on 'View->Tool Windows->Profiler'

Answer (score 0):

If you shake the device you can bring up the debug menu and enable perf.

Additionally if you're on iOS, xcode comes with a set of [performance tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/PerformanceTools/PerformanceTools.html). In spotlight, cmd + space, search for instruments, open it and select Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

[Performance](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html)

App developer menu - toggle Show Perf Monitor

[image: Perf Monitor]